# TypeError in Jest Test Suite: Issue with Mocking ReactReduxContext's displayName

Tags: reactjs, redux

During the execution of a Jest test suite, a critical error is encountered, specifically a TypeError related to the setting of the displayName property on an undefined object. This issue arises in the process of mocking the ReactReduxContext from the react-redux library.

The error is succinctly described as "Test suite failed to run | TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'displayName')". It is pinpointed to a specific line in the test code where ReactReduxContext is being extended with a custom displayName:

```
ReactReduxContext: {
...jest.requireActual('react-redux').ReactReduxContext,
 displayName: 'MockedReactReduxContext'
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against mocking internals from `react-redux` - I'm not sure what this export from `react-redux` is meant for, but for the purpose of unit-testing react components that use redux, the recommended approach is stated in the docs ( https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests ):

> For a React app using Redux, render a  with a real store instance wrapping the components being tested

The approaches I've seen in codebases use https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store for example. Using a library like that would probably circumvent your problem altogether.

`react-redux` also does not document `ReactReduxContext` under API here https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider - to me that's a hint that we're not supposed to use it for unit testing, unless you have a very special case that requires low-level parts of react-redux for some reason.